# How to manually specify the derby.system.home property to start a derby server

Tags: java, derby

I want to know a command to both Windows and Unix to start a Derby server at `localhost:1527` but with an specific `derby.system.home` property

From [here](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.4/adminguide/tadmincbdjhhfd.html) I could only understand to set the locations, the paths Java and Derby installation.

And the only thing about `derby.system.home` I found was [this](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.0/manuals/tuning/perf91.html).

Basically, I need a command to start the server the same way Netbeans does.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are starting the Derby Network Server using a technique similar to the ones documented in the Derby manuals (http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/getstart/twwdactivity2.html), you can control the derby.system.home value simply by adding:

```
-Dderby.system.home=/my/derby/home/dir
```

on the command line that you use to start the Derby Network Server.

If you're just getting started with the Derby Network Server, may I recommend working through the Derby "Getting Started" documentation at: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/getstart/