# Derby open a connection to database path on unix

Tags: spring, derby

I am unable to open a connection to the database outside derby system path in unix (CentOS) system.

```
<bean name="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>       
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:derby://127.0.0.1:1527/project/databases/customer;create=true"/>
    <property name="username" value="user"/>
    <property name="password" value="secret"/>
</bean>
```

could you please advise what needs to be done to fix this problem.

It works fine in windows.

For Ex. jdbc:derby://127.0.0.1:1527/f:/project/databases/customer;create=true

Comment: What is the error that you get? And what is in your Derby Network Server's derby.log?

Comment: @Bryan Pendleton - I don't get any error only thing I cannot specify database path outside of Derby home in CentOS but it works fine in Windows.

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting an error? When you say "I cannot specify database path outside of Derby home", it made me suspect you were getting a security error of some sort, but maybe what you mean is that you don't get an error, you just get an empty database, which is because you said `create=true` telling Derby that if there's no database at the path you specified, Derby should create a new empty database. So, which one is it, error or empty database?

Comment: @Bryan Pendleton - It is not the empty database. Derby is not allowing to create database outside of the path Derby is installed. For Ex. if Derby is installed in /home/derby and my connect string is this "jdbc:derby://127.0.0.1:1527/project/databases/customer;create=true". Then database is getting created under /home/derby/bin/project/databases/customer.

Comment: Ah, I think I'm getting closer to understanding your question. `/home/derby/bin` is the 'Derby System Home'. The path to the database is interpreted relative to the derby system home. I believe you can specify an absolute path name in your connection URL, but it is better, if possible, to control derby.system.home, for which see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26624031/how-to-manually-specify-the-derby-system-home-property-to-start-a-derby-server

Comment: But if you *really* want to specify an absolute filesystem path name in your JDBC Connection URL, that is possible too, though as I recall the syntax is a bit odd. I think you need either 1 or 2 extra slashes after the '1527'.